# Querying a JSON in a column in SQL and create a view

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, view

I have a table with JSON in one of the columns:

[image]

I need to create a view with columns as the Keys of the JSON. Since, the JSONs might have different keys, the selection of column has to be dynamic.

Comment: If the keys are dynamic, how do you expect to create the view? And if you could, how would you expect to consume it?

Comment: Dynamic in the sense that new keys could be added. The view will be created in a stored proc which will drop and re create the views when run.

Comment: Is there a way to select all keys from the json column without specifying the keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2016 and up you can use the `OPONJSON` function, however , you'll need to provide the path (inside the json code snippet), which can't be dynamic.

you can utilize the following user define function to extract all elements from the JSON up to the last level e.g. a JSON array/object inside the JSON itself.

this is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JsonTable] (@Json NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
WITH jsonRoot AS (
    SELECT 
        0 as parentLevel, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),NULL) as parentElementName, 
        0 AS [level], 
        [type] ,
        @Json  AS ElementName,
        [key]  as [Key],
        [value],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS ElementSequence
    FROM 
        OPENJSON(@Json, '$')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        jsonRoot.[level] as parentLevel, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),jsonRoot.ElementName)  as parentElementName, 
        jsonRoot.[level]+1 as [level], 
        d.[type] as [type],
        CASE WHEN jsonRoot.[type] IN (4,5) THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),jsonRoot.[Key]) ELSE jsonRoot.ElementName END  as ElementName,
        CASE WHEN jsonRoot.[type] IN (4) THEN jsonRoot.[Key] ELSE d.[key] END as [Key],
        d.[value],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ElementSequence
    FROM 
        jsonRoot
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsonRoot.[value], '$') d
    WHERE 
        jsonRoot.[type] IN (4,5) 

)

SELECT parentLevel , parentElementName ,[level] , [type] , ElementName , [Key] ,[value], ElementSequence
FROM jsonRoot
```

you can use it as follows:

```
SELECT type , x.*
FROM YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.JsonTable (t.JSON) x
```

This will break up the JSON into a table structure that you can work with in a stored procedure.

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @hkravitz. I ended up doing OpenJson to split the keys into row values and then doing a cursor to loop through and pick up those keys as columns.